AAPT2 process unexpectedly exit. Error output: aapt2 W 07-25 11:01:48 4839 56976 LoadedArsc.cpp:657] Unknown chunk type '200'
Facing issue while upgrading targetSdkVersion from 33 to 34
Different Versions mentioned below:
"react-native": "0.66.3"
gradle-wrapper.properties :
    distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip

android/build.gradle :
    ndkVersion = "23.2.8568313"
    buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 34
    targetSdkVersion = 34
    playServicesVersion = "17.0.0"
    kotlinVersion = "1.6.10"

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle:2.7.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }

Project running on Android Studio Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 2
Using Mac with Apple M2
I tried different versions of gradle till 4.2.2. I don't want to upgrade to latest versions as it will affect the dependencies.

Able to resolve this after upgrading gradle version
